# Can we use the simple present or simple past when talking about impossible or hypothetical situations?

Tags: meaning, tense, subjunctives

**Example 1**

> He talks with old-fashioned words like **a guy who travels in time a lot**.

In reality, it is impossible to travel in time, and we all know that.

Therefore, I am wondering whether I can use "a guy who travels in time a lot" here.

**Example 2**

> He looks out of breath and is panting like **a guy who just finished a marathon on Mars**.

In reality, it is impossible to run a marathon on Mars, and we all know that.

Therefore, I am wondering whether I can use "a guy who just finished a marathon on Mars" here.

**Example 3**

> He looks out of breath and is panting as a guy who runs marathons on Mars **would/does**.

Should we use "would" or "does" here?

Answer (score 1):

These are called exaggerations.

> He talks with old-fashioned words like a guy who travels in time a lot.

This sentence is grammatically correct, but "travels in time a lot" doesn't indicate that it is to the past.

I would use "back" here instead:

*He talks with old-fashioned words like a guy who travelled back in time.*

> He looks out of breath and is panting like a guy who just finished a marathon on Mars.

This sentence is very appropriate for this context, I believe it does not need to be changed.

> He looks out of breath and is panting as a guy who runs marathons on Mars would/does.

In this situation "would" is a better l option, since there isn't somebody for real running marathons on Mars. "would" is for imaginary events.

But, using "does" here would only make sense if you had somebody to refer to that actually did run a marathon on Mars, "does" is for real events.

So, it should be:

*He looks out of breath and is panting as a guy who runs marathons on Mars would.*

Answer (score -1):

Rather than use 'like', which draws a direct comparison (in this case to something that doesn't exist), you could use '*as if*' or '*as though*'. It is more common to use '*as if*' and '*as though*' to talk about an imaginary situation or a situation that may not be true but that is likely or possible.

For example:

> He spoke with old-fashioned words, as if he were a time traveller.

Comment: Might a time-traveller not speak with new-fashioned words from the future? In my 60s youth the _Doctor Who_ scriptwriters sometimes made 'future' people the Doctor encountered use invented words that were obvious in meaning, e.g. 'noovel' for 'new' that I recall.

Comment: This response should be a comment because it's not really answering the OP's questions.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm not questioning the OP's choice of words in that respect, just showing them how to use it properly.

Comment: @PoundHash I disagree. They've asked if their choice of words is correct when speaking about the impossible. I've said no, and given a better way to phrase it. What element of the question does it not answer?

Comment: The phrases in question are bolded. This is plain. You've chosen to address the word **like** which was obviously not a word the OP was asking about. Also, you didn't say **no**. You gave an alternative, which is not the same thing at all. Two alternatives can both be acceptable. Your answer doesn't rule out that **like** is acceptable, so you didn't say **no**, plainly.

Comment: The OP has given multiple *examples*, not multiple questions (that wouldn't be allowed by the site rules). There is no requirement to address each example. Questions on this site must be about learning English. Proofreading is off-topic. You'll find that most reputable contributors on this site try to show the OP how to understand their point of learning, and don't do their homework for them by correcting each example one by one.